# Caesar cipher program

Tags: c++

So far I have this

```
 #include <iostream>
 using namespace std;


string encryptText(string plaintext, int rshift)
{
    string t;

    for (int i=0;i<plaintext.length();i++)
    {

        if (islower(plaintext[i]))
            t += char(int(plaintext[i]+rshift-97)%26 +97);

        else if (isupper(plaintext[i]))
            t += char(int(plaintext[i]+rshift-65)%26 +65);
        else
            t;
    }

    return t;
}


int main()

{ 

    string plaintext, t;
    int rshift;

    cout << "enter the plaintext\n";
    getline (cin,plaintext);

    cout << "enter the right shift number\n";
    cin >> rshift;

    cout << encryptText (plaintext, rshift)<< endl;
}
```

The problem is that my program does not include the spaces from the user input (plaintext). Also, it does include the special charecters. For example, if I input

```
Hello World!
```

with a right shift of 10 I should get

```
Rovvy Gybvn!
```

but instead I get

```
RovvyGybvn
```

Comment: "*i should get Rovvy Gybvn!. bu instead i get Rovvy Gybvn!*" - ?

Comment: `else
            t;` does nothing.

Comment: Unrelated: Use `rshift-'a'` instead of `rshift-97`. 1. it's easier to infer intent. 2. it's portable to a wider variety of character sets.

Comment: I highly recommend searching the internet for "c++ caesar cipher example" or minimally, "stackoverflow c++ caesar cipher".  There are already a plethora of posts on this topic.

Comment: Prefer to use character literals, such as 'a', instead of their decimal ASCII encodings.

Comment: You don't need the `int` or `char` casts.  The `char` is already an integral type.

Comment: i changed my code according to all of your suggestions, but do you know how i can modify the last else statement so the if the charecter is something else besides an uppercase or lowecase letter it stays the same in the output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `else` block should be:

```
else
{
    t += plaintext[i];
}
```

If the character is not a letter, it is not appended to the string.  Run through your code with `plaintext[i] == '!'`.

Comment: if i want to decrypt the code such that the user inputs the encrypted text and the program outputs the actual sentece, what should i do? I tried a- rshift but that does not work.

Comment: To decrypt the code, add `(26 - rshift)` before using `%`.  Try it out with a debugger or calculator.